# Calculating sum of several records with different ID

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

When reaching last record, adding items "B" with same name "Y" (order by Y) I have:

```
  Do While Y < Z
      total=0
  Do While X=Y 
     Total = A + B (item to sum)
     MoveNext
  Loop
    MovePrevious
    DoCmd.RunSQL
   MoveNext
  Loop
  Close
```

it says no record found, it stops and does not record the value A (sum) on last record "Y". What am I missing?
Thank you.

Comment: It seems you have to check for `recordset.BOF` and/or `recordset.EOF`. These recordset properties state if you are before the first record (`BOF`) or behind the last one (`EOF`).

Comment: Use SQL and Group By

Comment: Thank you but did not work I wrote

Comment: I wrote 
`Do While recordset.BOF` and EOF but vba did no accept this command.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired result. Why not use query or report instead of VBA?

Comment: I want to colect date in a query using several tables and reccord each total in another table. I went to check and Access vba does not accept `recordset.BOF` with `Do While` and this requires something after `Do While`

Comment: Thank you again. I have 6 stores and several products in house. I need to colect value for each type of product for each store and recorde those values.

Comment: As per exemple above Y is ID of product, Z is last ID number of item (product). THe 2nd Do while counts how many products of each kind. Than I can have number of items, tupe and place, by store. Simple but when it reachs last item in last store it does not record, last quantity. Do while does not accept recordset or any EOF(). Thak you for your help.